# spark dataframe drop duplicates and keep first

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

Question: in pandas when dropping duplicates you can specify which columns to keep. Is there an equivalent in Spark Dataframes?

Pandas:

```
df.sort_values('actual_datetime', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['scheduled_datetime', 'flt_flightnumber'], keep='first')
```

Spark dataframe (I use Spark 1.6.0) doesn't have the keep option

```
df.orderBy(['actual_datetime']).dropDuplicates(subset=['scheduled_datetime', 'flt_flightnumber'])
```

Imagine `scheduled_datetime` and `flt_flightnumber` are columns 6 ,17. By creating keys based on the values of these columns we can also deduplicate

```
def get_key(x):
    return "{0}{1}".format(x[6],x[17])

df= df.map(lambda x: (get_key(x),x)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x))
```

but how to specify **to keep the first row** and get rid of the other duplicates ? What about the last row ?

Comment: When you run `dropDuplicates` you are keeping the first row per the columns combination specified and getting rid of the rest of the dupes. Are you sure your code isn't already doing what you want?

Comment: I tested and it seems the case indeed.

Comment: But then what to do if I want to keep the last row? I am looking only at one column for duplicate values

Comment: I think that if you want to keep the last row then you should sort descending first, and then drop duplicates.

Answer (score 123):

To everyone saying that dropDuplicates keeps the first occurrence - **this is not strictly correct.**

dropDuplicates keeps the 'first occurrence' of a sort operation - only if there is 1 partition. See below for some examples.
However this is not practical for most Spark datasets. So I'm also including an example of 'first occurrence' drop duplicates operation using Window function + sort + rank + filter.
*See bottom of post for example.*

*This is tested in Spark 2.4.0 using pyspark.*

### dropDuplicates examples

```py
import pandas as pd

# generating some example data with pandas, will convert to spark df below
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df1['datestr'] = '2018-01-01'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df2['datestr'] = '2018-02-01'
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df3['datestr'] = '2018-03-01'
dfall = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
print(dfall)
```

```
   col1     datestr
0     0  2018-01-01
1     1  2018-01-01
2     2  2018-01-01
3     3  2018-01-01
4     4  2018-01-01
0     0  2018-02-01
1     1  2018-02-01
2     2  2018-02-01
3     3  2018-02-01
4     4  2018-02-01
0     0  2018-03-01
1     1  2018-03-01
2     2  2018-03-01
3     3  2018-03-01
4     4  2018-03-01
```

```py
# first example
# does not give first (based on datestr)
(spark.createDataFrame(dfall)
   .orderBy('datestr')
   .dropDuplicates(subset = ['col1'])
   .show()
)

# dropDuplicates NOT based on occurrence of sorted datestr
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-03-01|
|   1|2018-02-01|
|   3|2018-02-01|
|   2|2018-02-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

```py
# second example
# testing what happens with repartition
(spark.createDataFrame(dfall)
   .orderBy('datestr')
   .repartition('datestr')
   .dropDuplicates(subset = ['col1'])
   .show()
)

# dropDuplicates NOT based on occurrence of sorted datestr
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-02-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-02-01|
|   2|2018-02-01|
|   4|2018-02-01|
+----+----------+
```

```py
#third example
# testing with coalesce(1)
(spark
   .createDataFrame(dfall)
   .orderBy('datestr')
   .coalesce(1)
   .dropDuplicates(subset = ['col1'])
   .show()
)

# dropDuplicates based on occurrence of sorted datestr
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

````py
# fourth example
# testing with reverse sort then coalesce(1)
(spark
   .createDataFrame(dfall)
   .orderBy('datestr', ascending = False)
   .coalesce(1)
   .dropDuplicates(subset = ['col1'])
   .show()
)
# dropDuplicates based on occurrence of sorted datestr```
````

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-03-01|
|   1|2018-03-01|
|   2|2018-03-01|
|   3|2018-03-01|
|   4|2018-03-01|
+----+----------+
```

### window, sort, rank, filter example

```py
# generating some example data with pandas
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df1['datestr'] = '2018-01-01'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df2['datestr'] = '2018-02-01'
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df3['datestr'] = '2018-03-01'
dfall = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
# into spark df
df_s = (spark.createDataFrame(dfall))
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank
window = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("datestr")
(df_s.withColumn('rank', rank().over(window))
.filter(col('rank') == 1)
.drop('rank')
.show()
)
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

```py
# however this fails if ties/duplicates exist in the windowing paritions
# and so a tie breaker for the 'rank' function must be added

# generating some example data with pandas, will convert to spark df below
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df1['datestr'] = '2018-01-01'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df2['datestr'] = '2018-01-01' # note duplicates in this dataset
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df3['datestr'] = '2018-03-01'
dfall = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
print(dfall)
```

```
   col1     datestr
0     0  2018-01-01
1     1  2018-01-01
2     2  2018-01-01
3     3  2018-01-01
4     4  2018-01-01
0     0  2018-01-01
1     1  2018-01-01
2     2  2018-01-01
3     3  2018-01-01
4     4  2018-01-01
0     0  2018-03-01
1     1  2018-03-01
2     2  2018-03-01
3     3  2018-03-01
4     4  2018-03-01
```

```py
# this will fail, since duplicates exist within the window partitions
# and no way to specify ranking style exists in pyspark rank() fn
window = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("datestr")
(df_s.withColumn('rank', rank().over(window))
.filter(col('rank') == 1)
.drop('rank')
.show()
)
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

```py
# to deal with ties within window partitions, a tiebreaker column is added
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col, monotonically_increasing_id
window = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("datestr",'tiebreak')
(df_s
 .withColumn('tiebreak', monotonically_increasing_id())
 .withColumn('rank', rank().over(window))
 .filter(col('rank') == 1).drop('rank','tiebreak')
 .show()
)
```

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

Comment: I tested with real dataset(500k+), .coalesce(1) is required.

Comment: None of the above gives the right answer. We need a better answer for this post.

Comment: This answer is almost the optimal. Instead of 'rank' which allows ties to share the same rank, use the row_number() function in place of rank(). This is simpler than using a tiebreaker column.

Comment: Good examples, but coalesce(1) pushes all data to driver and with bigger volume you will run into memory problems

Comment: Joey Lesh is Right. Check the answer by Alex right at the bottom that combines the solution as per Joey's input.

Comment: Almost optimal answer

Answer (score 18):

Use `window` and `row_number` functions.
Order by ascending or descending to select first or last.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

window = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("datestr").asc()
df = (df.withColumn('row', f.row_number().over(window))\
.filter(col('row') == 1)
.drop('row')
.show())
```

Comment: This answer already exists https://stackoverflow.com/a/58540058/1386551

Comment: no need for asc(). Default behavior of orderBy is already ascending

Comment: does paritionBy and row_number also result in pushing all data into driver. Similar to how it does for coalesce(1) as mentioned in the top answer.?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a window with row_number:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df1['datestr'] = '2018-01-01'
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df2['datestr'] = '2018-02-01'
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':range(0,5)})
df3['datestr'] = '2018-03-01'
dfall = spark.createDataFrame(pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]))

from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col,row_number
window = Window.partitionBy('col1').orderBy(col('datestr'))
dfall.select('*', row_number().over(window).alias('posicion')).show()
dfall.select('*', row_number().over(window).alias('posicion')).where('posicion ==1').show()

+----+----------+--------+
|col1|   datestr|posicion|
+----+----------+--------+
|   0|2018-01-01|       1|
|   0|2018-02-01|       2|
|   0|2018-03-01|       3|
|   1|2018-01-01|       1|
|   1|2018-02-01|       2|
|   1|2018-03-01|       3|
|   3|2018-01-01|       1|
|   3|2018-02-01|       2|
|   3|2018-03-01|       3|
|   2|2018-01-01|       1|
|   2|2018-02-01|       2|
|   2|2018-03-01|       3|
|   4|2018-01-01|       1|
|   4|2018-02-01|       2|
|   4|2018-03-01|       3|
+----+----------+--------+
+----+----------+--------+
|col1|   datestr|posicion|
+----+----------+--------+
|   0|2018-01-01|       1|
|   1|2018-01-01|       1|
|   3|2018-01-01|       1|
|   2|2018-01-01|       1|
|   4|2018-01-01|       1|
+----+----------+--------+
```

Answer (score 5):

I did the following:

```
dataframe.groupBy("uniqueColumn").min("time")
```

This will group by the given column, and within the same group choose the one with min time (this will keep the first and remove others)

Comment: Care to elaborate @mahmoud-hanafy? 

Using goupyby and min/max is clear.. but how does this solve the duplicates problem? How can we ensure that rows with the min time are always kept?

Comment: Hi KevinG, you need to understand how groupBy works.
If you have a List((0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 4)) then you do groupBy(_._1) you will have => Map(0 -> List(1, 2, 3), 1 -> List(4)). 
Then when choosing the min one of the values you will have => Map(0 -> 1, 1 -> 4). So duplicate values will be removed and you will keep the min one only

Comment: You will need a subsequent join to keep any additional columns, though.

Answer (score 4):

**solution 1**
add a new column row num(incremental column) and drop duplicates based the min row after grouping on all the columns you are interested in.(you can include all the columns for dropping duplicates except the row num col)

**solution 2:**
turn the data-frame into a rdd (df.rdd) then group the rdd on one or more or all keys and then run a lambda function on the group and drop the rows the way you want and return only the row that you are interested in.

**One of my friend (sameer) mentioned that below(old solution) didn't work for him.**
use dropDuplicates method by default it keeps the first occurance.

Comment: can you please provide a valid source ?

Comment: @Manrique - Docs are here -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates

Comment: Thanks @GunayAnach, but I can't see in that doc that by default dropDuplicates keeps the first occurrence.

Comment: It seems to be based on pandas, where -> keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html

But you are right, not specified on the docs. They seem rather dry, compared to pandas.

Comment: How can i keep last element in scala

Answer (score 2):

I just did something perhaps similar to what you guys need, using drop_duplicates pyspark.

Situation is this. I have 2 dataframes (coming from 2 files) which are exactly same except 2 columns file_date(file date extracted from the file name) and data_date(row date stamp). Annoyingly I have rows which are with same data_date (and all other column cells too) but different file_date as they get replicated on every newcomming file with an addition of one new row.

I needed to capture all rows from the new file, plus that one row left over from the previous file. That row is not in the new file. Remaining columns on the right from data_date are same between the two files for the same data_date.

```
file_1_20190122 - df1

+------------+----------+----------+
|station_code| file_date| data_date|
+------------+----------+----------+
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-16| <- One row we want to keep where file_date 22nd
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-17|
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-18|
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-19|
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-20|
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-21|
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-22|


file_2_20190123 - df2

+------------+----------+----------+
|station_code| file_date| data_date|
+------------+----------+----------+
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-17| \/ ALL rows we want to keep where file_date 23rd
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-18|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-19|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-20|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-21|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-22|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-23|
```

This will require us to sort and concat df's, then deduplicate them on all columns but one.
Let me walk you through.

```
union_df = df1.union(df2) \
                .sort(['station_code', 'data_date'], ascending=[True, True])

+------------+----------+----------+
|station_code| file_date| data_date|
+------------+----------+----------+
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-16| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-17| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-17| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-18| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-18| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-19| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-19| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-20| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-20| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-21| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-21| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-22| <- keep
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-22| x- drop
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-23| <- keep
```

Here we drop already sorted duped rows excluding keys **['file_date', 'data_date']**.

```
nonduped_union_df = union_df \
            .drop_duplicates(['station_code', 'data_date', 'time_zone', 
                              'latitude', 'longitude', 'elevation', 
                              'highest_temperature', 'lowest_temperature', 
                              'highest_temperature_10_year_normal', 
                              'another_50_columns'])
```

And the result holds ONE row with earliest date from DF1 which is not in DF2 and ALL rows from DF2

```
nonduped_union_df.select(['station_code', 'file_date', 'data_date', 
                          'highest_temperature', 'lowest_temperature']) \
                         .sort(['station_code', 'data_date'], ascending=[True, True]) \
                         .show(30)


+------------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|station_code| file_date| data_date|highest_temperature|lowest_temperature|
+------------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
|        AGGH|2019-01-22|2019-01-16|                 90|                77| <- df1 22nd
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-17|                 90|                77| \/- df2 23rd
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-18|                 91|                75|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-19|                 88|                77|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-20|                 88|                77|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-21|                 88|                77|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-22|                 90|                75|
|        AGGH|2019-01-23|2019-01-23|                 90|                75|
|        CWCA|2019-01-22|2019-01-15|                 23|                -2|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-16|                  7|                -8|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-17|                 28|                -6|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-18|                  0|               -13|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-19|                 25|               -15|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-20|                 -4|               -18|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-21|                 27|                -6|
|        CWCA|2019-01-22|2019-01-22|                 30|                17|
|        CWCA|2019-01-23|2019-01-22|                 30|                13|
|        CWCO|2019-01-22|2019-01-15|                 34|                29|
|        CWCO|2019-01-23|2019-01-16|                 33|                13|
|        CWCO|2019-01-22|2019-01-16|                 33|                13|
|        CWCO|2019-01-22|2019-01-17|                 23|                 7|
|        CWCO|2019-01-23|2019-01-17|                 23|                 7|
+------------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------+
only showing top 30 rows
```

It may not be best suitable answer for this case, but it's the one worked for me.

Let me know, if stuck somewhere.

*BTW - if anyone can tell me how to select all columns in a df, except one without listing them in a list - I will be very thankful.*

Regards
G

Comment: how to select all columns in a df, except one : 
`all_columns_but_one = [c for c in df.columns if c!="undesired_column_name"]
df = df.select(all_columns_but_one)`

Answer (score 1):

I would try this way:

Assuming your data_df looks like this, and we want to keep the rows with the highest value in col1 per datestr:

```
  col1     datestr
     0  2018-01-01
     1  2018-01-01
     2  2018-01-01
     3  2018-01-01
     4  2018-01-01
     0  2018-02-01
     1  2018-02-01
     2  2018-02-01
     3  2018-02-01
     4  2018-02-01
     0  2018-03-01
     1  2018-03-01
     2  2018-03-01
     3  2018-03-01
     4  2018-03-01
```

you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('datestr')
data_df = data_df.withColumn("max", F.max(F.col("col1"))\
    .over(w))\
    .where(F.col('max') == F.col('col1'))\
    .drop("max")
```

this results in:

```
  col1     datestr
     4  2018-01-01
     4  2018-02-01
     4  2018-03-01
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the below table:

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
|   0|2018-02-01|
|   1|2018-02-01|
|   2|2018-02-01|
|   3|2018-02-01|
|   4|2018-02-01|
|   0|2018-03-01|
|   1|2018-03-01|
|   2|2018-03-01|
|   3|2018-03-01|
|   4|2018-03-01|
+----+----------+
```

You can do it in two steps:

Group by the given table based upon the col1 and pick min date.

```
+----+----------+
|col1|   datestr|
+----+----------+
|   0|2018-01-01|
|   1|2018-01-01|
|   2|2018-01-01|
|   3|2018-01-01|
|   4|2018-01-01|
+----+----------+
```

left Join the resultant table with original table on col1 and min_datestr.

Answer (score -1):

if datasets isnt not large convert to pandas data frame and drop duplicates keeping last or first then convert back.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for sharing your thoughts .The question is not asking whether to use a pandas DF or Spark DF. Changing technologies isn't simple.Please read the questions in detail.