# Apache PySpark - Get latest record issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

We have ~100M records, that have been collected for 2 weeks. Same records can appear multiple times. For the duplicated records, I only need the latest one based on the "LastModified" date.

I have tried with the following Spark script but it seemed to pickup the value randomly.

```
df.orderBy(unix_timestamp(df["LastModified"], "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a").desc()).dropDuplicates(["LastModified"])
```

I have checked the data, the date format, ... all looked good.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Look at this answer: It can be the reason https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738843/2700344  If the DF has many partitions, df.dropDuplicates works for data in the partition

Comment: @Tuong Le..did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Yep, please follow the above link