# dropDuplicates() not working with pyspark but works with spark java

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a single transformation whose sole purpose is to drop duplicates. When using [PySpark 2.x](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates), the resulting output removes some duplicates, but not all. When using [Apache Spark Java 2.x](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html), the resulting output is as expected with all duplicates removed.

I am currently running Spark on YARN. *My dataset is roughly 125 millions rows by 200 columns. It is expected that certain columns contain null values.* For my use case, I do indeed have pure duplicates (reasons for this are out of scope). So far, I have tried:

1. dropDuplicates(df.columns) / dropDuplicates(), PySpark -> drops some but not all duplicates
2. distinct(), PySpark -> drops some but not all duplicates, different row count than 1.
3. dropDuplicates([primary_key_I_created]), PySpark -> works
4. dropDuplicates(dataset.columns()), Apache Spark Java -> works

I inspected the physical plans, and both method 1 and method 4 produce identical plans. They are roughly as follows:

```
+-HashAggregate(keys=[column_1, column_2, .... 198 more fields], functions=[], output=[column_1, column_2, ... 198 more fields]
  +-Exchange hashpartitioning(column_1, column_2, ... 198 more fields)
    +-HashAggregate(keys=[column_1, column_2, .... 198 more fields], functions=[], output=[column_1, column_2, ... 198 more fields]
      +-FileScan parquet ....
```

Below is an example of a pair of rows that are duplicates that did not get dropped. I confirmed that there are no weird whitespace errors by running dropDuplicates() on JUST those two rows. That run worked as expected by returning a single row.

```
column_1 | column_2 | column_3 | column_4 | column_5| ..... column_200
 bob        jones     **null**   **null**   200.00           30
 bob        jones     **null**   **null**   200.00           30
```

Is there something happening under the hood that would cause PySpark to fail, but Spark Java to succeed (apologies for my vague jargon here)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `df.dropDuplicates()` (i.e. without parameter) also work?

Comment: Neither df.dropDuplicates() nor df.distinct() works; they both drop some but not all duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean with all duplicates?

Comment: In addition to thebluephantom. Can you please give us an example of rows which weren't dropped?

Comment: absolutely, I updated the question

Comment: The [source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html#DataFrame.dropDuplicates) is calling `jdf = self._jdf.dropDuplicates()
` directly without any modification. How do you determine that one of the listed ways doesn't contain duplicates while another does? By calling df.count()?

Comment: It may not be related to this problem but here's some good case study on drop duplicates .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687212/spark-dataframe-drop-duplicates-and-keep-first/54738843#

Comment: *a rather unsatisfying answer* I needed to upgrade to a later version of pySpark, and this seemed to resolve the issue ... but to answer questions above, yes I was calling count to verify row counts because I was seeing weird data issues downstream

Comment: @Jesse..would you like to share us your findings as an answer here. Thanks