# Summarizing labels at time steps based on current and past info

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given the following input dataframe

```
npos = 3

inp = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['1', 23, 0, 2],
    ['1', 45, 1, 2],
    ['1', 89, 1, 3],
    ['1', 95, 2, 2],
    ['1', 95, 0, 4],
    ['2', 20, 2, 2],
    ['2', 40, 1, 4],
  ], schema=["id","elap","pos","lbl"])
```

A dataframe which looks like this needs to be constructed

```
out = spark.createDataFrame([
    ['1', 23, [2,0,0]],
    ['1', 45, [2,2,0]],
    ['1', 89, [2,3,0]],
    ['1', 95, [4,3,2]],
    ['2', 20, [0,0,2]],
    ['2', 40, [0,4,2]],
  ], schema=["id","elap","vec"])
```

The input dataframe has 10s of millions of records.

Some details which are seen in the example above (by design)

- `npos` is the size of the vector to be constructed in the output
- `pos` is guaranteed to be in `[0,npos)`
- at each time step (`elap`) there will be at most 1 `label` for a `pos`
- if `lbl` is not given at a time step it has to be inferred from the last time it was specified for that `pos`
- if `lbl` is not previously specified, it can be assumed to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some higher-order functions on arrays to achieve that:

1. add `vec` column using `array_repeat` function and initialize `pos` value from `lbl`
2. use `collect_list` to get cumulative `vec` over window partitioned by `id`
3. `aggregate` the resulting array by selecting previous positions if it is different from `0`

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

npos = 3

out = inp.withColumn(
    "vec",
    F.expr(f"transform(array_repeat(0, {npos}), (x, i) -> IF(i=pos, lbl, x))")
).withColumn(
    "vec",
    F.collect_list("vec").over(Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("elap"))
).withColumn(
    "vec",
    F.expr(f"""aggregate(
                  vec, 
                  array_repeat(0, {npos}),
                  (acc, x) -> transform(acc, (y, i) -> int(IF(x[i]!=0, x[i], y)))
            )""")
).drop("lbl", "pos")

out.show(truncate=False)

#+---+----+---------+
#|id |elap|vec      |
#+---+----+---------+
#|1  |23  |[2, 0, 0]|
#|1  |45  |[2, 2, 0]|
#|1  |89  |[2, 3, 0]|
#|1  |95  |[4, 3, 2]|
#|1  |95  |[4, 3, 2]|
#|2  |20  |[0, 0, 2]|
#|2  |40  |[0, 4, 2]|
#+---+----+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks!  Rows 4 and 5 are the same.  Run a distinct on the entire df at the end or is there a better way?

Comment: To get another example, you can change `elap` in the second row to 23.  Then rows 1 & 2 get duplicated.  `distinct()` gets rid of that.  Your thoughts?

Comment: @ironv if you don't care of which row to preserve then you could do `inp.dropDuplicates["id", "elap"]` before doing above transformations. Otherwise you can use use [Window with row_number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687212/spark-dataframe-drop-duplicates-and-keep-first) to eliminate duplicates according to certain order you define.

Comment: Thx.  I went with `.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(W.partitionBy("id","elap").orderBy(F.desc("pos")))).filter(F.col("rn")==1).drop("rn","pos","lbl")` after the `collect_list` line.

Comment: For the part of the code which says `IF(i=pos, lbl, x)` does there need to be `==`?  Both seem to work though!

Comment: Can you pls point me to a good resource (with examples) which will help me learn about `pySpark` `tranform()`?  Seems really powerful and an excellent tool to have in one's toolkit and know well.