# is there anyway I can maintain the sort order while droping by subset by keeping the first

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to maintain a sort order while removing the duplicates with one common column among both.
My table looks similar to this

| index_id | sim_score | cond | cond1 | mode | file_id | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 130 | 364 | FALSE | FALSE | airplane | nan | It was nice flight |
| 130 | 364 | FALSE | FALSE | car | nan | 4 seating comfortable |
| 130 | 0 | FALSE | FALSE | car | nan | don’t prefer diesel one |
| 131 | 96 | FALSE | FALSE | bus | nan | correct timing is difficult to achieve |
| 131 | 46 | FALSE | FALSE | bus | nan | too calculated |
| 131 | 0 | FALSE | FALSE | car | nan | need expensive car |
| 131 | 171 | FALSE | FALSE | bus | nan | bust stations need to be found |
| 130 | 239 | FALSE | FALSE | walk | nan | Too slow |
| 130 | 164 | FALSE | FALSE | airplane | nan | It was nice flight |
| 130 | 266 | FALSE | FALSE | scooter | nan | No protection from rain |

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
custom_dict = {'car': 0, 'airplane': 1}

map_col = F.create_map([F.lit(x) for x in chain(*custom_dict.items())])

#sorting
df_sort = df.sort(
col("index_id").asc(),
col("sim_score").asc(),
col("cond").desc(),
col("cond1").desc(),
map_col.getItem(col("mode")).asc())

#remove duplicates by subset
df_sort.dropDuplicates(subset=['index_id','text','file_id'])
```

I am aware that drop Duplicates shuffle. I have seen several examples of the similar problem but did not come across the solution to maintain the sort order and remove the first and note that they are different. My dataframe is around a maximum of around 6000 or so rows. A bit of efficient method would be great, and don't want to convert to a pandas dataframe as well.

Comment: create a `row_number()` based on partition+sort and then filter the first row (`=1`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark dataframe drop duplicates and keep first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687212/spark-dataframe-drop-duplicates-and-keep-first)